# What is the difference between literature and review study?

Tags: publishing, reviews

I had submitted a review article few days before and I have received a comment from an editor of a journal. The comment is " Is it literature or review study"?

I am wondering that I had submitted a literature review but he has coined something new that I am unable to understand? What does he mean by this?

I need help over this.

Answer (score 2):

It's likely a sarcastic way of asking you whether you are writing a review study, which is the review article you intended to write, or a piece of literature, meaning prose, which is likely not what the editor wants - he wants the article, not a novel.

This means that your writing may be extravagant, or you may not be focusing as much on the facts as the editor would expect you to do for the kind of article you want to publish. Basically your style seems to fit better for creative writing than for review articles.

In any case: the editor is the only one who can tell you what he really means. For me it sounds like a sarcastic comment... and a bit unprofessional from the editor...